# Printing objects fields in django template (Not from model)

Tags: python, django, templates

I want to print the values of the objects in a list I calculate in views.py

```
list = comparation.ClientAssetCompare(request.user)
t = get_template('profile/temp.html')
c = template.Context({'user' : request.user ,'vuln' : list })
```

And in the template I try to get the fields of my custom object (NOT in database, calculated by the program):

```
{% for elem in vuln %}

<td>{{ elem.vendor }}</td>
<td>{{ elem.software }}</td>
<td>{{ elem.version }}</td>>
```

The object is something like this basically:

```
class Notification:
def __init__(self):

    self.vendor= 'something'
    self.software = 'something'
    self.version = 'something'
```

But I get no values.. If i print {{elem}} it prints the tostring() method in my object.
Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of whatever the object is?

Comment: Nevermind, it was my fault, I was saving the tostring of the object instead of the object itself, sorry!